# Recurrent Sequences

Tags: sequences-and-series, recurrence-relations

I want some help, please, to solve this problem.
Let 
$$\begin{cases}x_0=a, a>1\\x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+\big(n+1\big)x_n^2}\end{cases}$$
I want to prove that $\forall n\in\mathbb{N}^*,\ 0<x_n\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$
I proved that $x_n$ is bounded from below by $0$, but I can't figure out how to prove that $x_n\leq\frac{1}{n+1}$ .

I used the **Mathematical Induction** method, so for $n=1$ we have : $x_1=\frac{1}{2}$
Then the statement, in this case, is satisfied. Next, we assume another real non-null number $k/\ x_k⩽\frac{1}{n+1}$, and we prove that $x_{k+1}⩽\frac{1}{n+2}$, but I'm stuck.

So please help me if you can. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For these types of expressions,
I often find it useful
to take the reciprocal.

$x_{n+1}=\frac{x_n}{1+\big(n+1\big)x_n^2}
$
becomes
$\dfrac1{x_{n+1}}
=\dfrac{1+\big(n+1\big)x_n^2}{x_n}
=\dfrac1{x_n}+(n+1)x_n
$.

Letting
$y_n = \dfrac1{x_n}$,
this becomes
$y_{n+1}
=y_n+\dfrac{n+1}{y_n}
=\dfrac{y_n^2+n+1}{y_n}
$,
so we need
$y_n^2+n+1
\gt (n+2)y_n
$
or
$y_n^2-(n+2)y_n+n+1
\gt 0
$
or
$y_n^2-2(n/2+1)y_n+(n/2+1)^2-(n/2+1)^2+n+1
\gt 0
$
or
$(y_n-(n/2+1))^2-n^2/4-n-1+n+1
\gt 0
$
or
$(y_n-(n/2+1))^2
\gt n^2/4
$.

Since
$y_n > n+1$,
$y_n-(n/2+1)
\gt n+1-(n/2+1)
=n/2
$,
so
$(y_n-(n/2+1))^2
\gt n^2/4
$
which is what we want.

Therefore
$x_n \lt \dfrac1{n+1}$.

Comment: Thanks! This is helpful!